# react-native-svg-charts installation failed

Tags: react-native, npm, svg, installation, charts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZg0s.png)

I tried to install the npm from https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts to my project. Unfortunately, error always popped out as shown in the picture. Most of the npm are able to be install as usual but when it came to this npm, I can`t install it. So, I am here to seek advise from you all.

Answer (score 0):

The latest stable release of react-native-svg-charts is currently 5.3.0 so try installing that version instead. Find the line requesting that library in your package.json and change the version number to 5.3.0, then try installing all your node packages again.

https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts/releases